# Событие Form.Closing и Form.Closed

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне кажется, событие Form.Closing можно использовать лишь в некоторых ограниченных ситуациях, таких как, например, запрос на подтверждение закрытия программы или нечто подобное. Но в различных уроках, на разных примерах, и в других исходниках программ, почти всегда встречаю именно Form.Closing, и никогда Form.Closed.

Я что-то не понимаю?

Я, как новичок, по их примеру тоже засовываю всё в Form.Closing, и, как следствие, программа теперь неприлично подвисает на секунду перед закрытием, выполняя различный код.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, довольно очевидно, что в `Closing` должен быть код, в результате выполнения которого может выясниться, что форму закрывать не надо. +1 за креативную картинку.

Comment: _Кто умеет - тот делает. Кто не умеет делать - тот руководит. Кто не умеет руководить - тот учит._ Уроки, примеры и туториалы пишут последние...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по факту мы тоже тут учим... :)

Comment: То что программа не отображается, не означает что она не работает. Пользователь может нажать на крестик и, убедившись что программа закрылась, выдернуть компьютер из электросети, в то время как программа еще не окончила работу с данными. Данные будут испорчены. Конечно, все зависит от ситуации и задач. Во всяком случае, я не встречал официальных рекомендаций по использованию `Closing` и `Closed`. Поэтому считаю, что вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, а ответы будут основан не на знаниях, а на мнениях авторов.

Answer (score 3):

Как правило, в `Form.Closing` присутствует логика, относящаяся к проверке на закрытие самого окна непосредственно. Т.е логика, которая проверяет авторизацию, либо просит подтверждения, либо еще что-то. Логика, которая может повлиять на то, разрешать ли закрыть окно.

В `Form.Closed` должна присутствовать логика, которая либо диспоузит что-либо, либо подготавливает данные для использования извне и т.д. В общем, вся остальная, необходимая при закрытии окна.

Так же стоит заметить, что нельзя любые видеоуроки на `youtube` воспринимать как должные. Там пишут бесплатный код на скорую руку в основном.